# Android Studio does not see my physical device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb

I connected my phone to the computer, but Android Studio does not display it. The computer displays the phone but Android Studio does not. I tried to change phone and cable but nothing happens.
I have already activated the debugging of the phone, but in any case the device does not appear on the list of available devices. Some advice?

Comment: first of all check `adb` devices. and second check `dev-options`. For more information you can read from official doc  https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options

Comment: Did you press the build number 7 times? After this you still need to turn on usb debugging

Comment: Thanks, but I already did it. 
I forgot to mention this in the problem description, sorry.

Comment: Execute in a commandline/terminal or powershell `adb devices` to check if adb sees your device. Copy the command + output and add it to your question.

Answer (score 4):

You Have to Enable `Developer Options` in your phone and from there enable the `USB Debugging` and when you reconnect the cable you will see a popup on your phone to allow debug session from the connected PC and say `yes` and you will be able to see your physical device in the device list.

To enable the `Developer Options` there are already many articles on the internet. in most cases you have to click your `Build Number` a bunch of times till you see a toast saying `You Are Now A developer`

Comment: I have already activated the USB debugging. In the pop-up I have given availability for the file transfer but in any case nothing appears in the list of devices on Android Studio. Sorry if I didn't specify this in the problem description, my fault.